# Came across some code syntax i didnt know. Can anyone explain

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

This code is

```
_gradientLayer.locations = @[@0.00f, @0.01f, @0.95f, @1.00f];
```

I know it declares an array but where would I find any reference to read more about it.

Comment: DO you want to understand array or gradient ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is new added Literals in Obj-c.

> Users of Apple compiler releases can use these features starting with
>   the Apple LLVM Compiler 4.0. Users of open-source LLVM.org compiler
>   releases can use these features starting with clang v3.1.

You find it in compilers running XCode4.4 and above.

Find [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) full reference.

Comment: came back to paste the same link and there you were.

Comment: sorry, was just saying you and i were googling "clang literals" at the very same moment.  +1

Answer (score 2):

_gradientLayer is a CAGradient Layer, you have to define locations and color array to add gradient to gradient layer.

```
CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
layer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                (id)[[UIColor darkKinepolisColor] CGColor],
                (id)[[UIColor lightKinepolisColor] CGColor],
                (id)[[UIColor lightKinepolisColor] CGColor],
                (id)[[UIColor darkKinepolisColor] CGColor],
                nil];
layer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00],
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.01],
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.95],
                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                   nil];
```

Here it is used like

```
_gradientLayer.locations = @[@0.00f, @0.01f, @0.95f, @1.00f];
_gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor darkKinepolisColor] CGColor],
            (id)[[UIColor lightKinepolisColor] CGColor],
            (id)[[UIColor lightKinepolisColor] CGColor],
            (id)[[UIColor darkKinepolisColor] CGColor]];
```

Old way of array is replaced with new annotations